# Incron executes only once

Tags: incrontab, incrond

I have an incron configured , in the incrontab. The event gets executed only once after the reload and incron disables the watch after that and the event does not get triggered by incrontab table looks like

> /unmetric_ebs/unmetric/props/unmetric-conf.properties
>   IN_MODIFY,IN_CLOSE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE /bin/sh
>   /root/inotify.sh
>   /unmetric_ebs/unmetric/props/unmetric-conf.properties

Could you please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in incrond. Nothing the [incron docs](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en) mentions triggering only once per event vs each time. Considering the software is labeled "alpha quality", it sounds like a bug in the software. Consider inquiring with the developers.

I'm not sure what you are trying solve, but consider that systemd-based systems support activating services based on [inotify events](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html). This functionality is available by default on a number of Linux distributions now and is considered production-ready. Consider investigating using `systemd` instead.